# How do I add a class based on a complex angular logical expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to set a class to a button based on the value of the expression as follows

```
ng-class="{disabled:((post_data.somearray.length==0) && (!post_data.message))}
```

I am trying to check if the length of some items are selected and if a message is present proceed else add class disabled to the button.

If I only try this,

```
ng-class="{disabled: (!post_data.message)}
```

and it evaluates to FALSE the class is added but it fails if I add the && i.e., AND condition.

How do I check an AND expression?

Comment: It should work. Either the expression is being evaluated to false or there is an error. In your html put this expression {{((post_data.somearray.length==0) && (!post_data.message))}} anywhere and see what the value is.

Comment: Thank you the expression was actually evaluating to false.